# RegEx to account for null string

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regex for my SIEM to capture the Caller Computer Name for Windows Security Event 4740 - User Account Lockout.

The problem is that sometimes the "Caller Computer Name" field has a null or empty value and my regex does not account for it. The residual affect is that it is causing syntax problems in my custom email notification any time an event is captured with a blank value.

See [link](https://regex101.com/r/aJLL55/1) on Regex101:

```
Caller Computer Name:\s+([^ ]+)
```

The second occurrence of `Caller Computer Name:` is not found, but I want to find that substring. How do I write a Regex that accounts for either condition? Whether there is a value or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex will match if there is an empty value since `*` matches for 0 or more oven if there is no character following the String.

```
/Caller Computer Name:\s*[^ ]*/
```

Comment: I wrapped this as a capture group and it appears to have resolved the xml issue in my email notification. The field not just shown "blank". `Caller Computer Name:(\s*[^ ]*)`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Caller Computer Name:\s*(\S*)
```

The `\S*` matches 0 or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQxqIV/1).

**Full pattern details**:

- `Caller Computer Name:` - a literal `Caller Computer Name:` substring
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `(\S*)` - a capturing group #1 that matches 0 or more chars other than whitespace.

Note there is a difference between `(\S+)?` and `(\S*)` in Java: the first group will be null if there is no value, and the second one will be initialized with an empty string.

Comment: "s* - 1 or more whitespace chars" typo. should be 0 or more